# CPU multithreading for OR-tools CP-SAT

Tags: python, or-tools, cp-sat

I have developed a model in OR-tools using its CP-SAT solver (python). The model seeks to determine some optimal order which can be considered a sorft of TSP problem. This has been working well, and might be used by others in the form of a .exe.

From what i've read and experienced, CP-SAT benefits from more cores/threads.I currently use a (laptop) i5-1335u, 8 threads which has reasonable speed. I am wondering about the following;

Question 1: would a (desktop) CPU with a higher clock speed and increased number of threads (e.g. 16) yield significant reduction in computation time? Which of the two has the most benefit?

Question 2: Should there be a focus on something like 4/8/16 threads, or does any number threads > 1 improve speed?

Thanks in advance.

P.S, I use OR-tools TSP as an initial solution to the problem, oftenwise the CP-SAT is able to find a marginally better solution, therefore I don't want to resort to merely the TSP implementation.

I tried the model on another device with an i5-1135G7 which produced similar results in terms of computation time. I do not have acces to any other hardware as of now.

Comment: To know if increasing clock frequency or number of cores significantly improve the performance depends on the problem and its size. Does this problem gets solved in microseconds? miliseconds? More? Anyway, increasing the number of core for a big problem is a good idea if and only if you have the RAM that goes with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a section on this:

https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/stable/ortools/sat/docs/troubleshooting.md#improving-performance-with-multiple-workers

Tldr: go to 16 workers